# docker containers permission denied when trying to save edited file

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, containers

When I edit a file in a docker container it asks for preforming the save action using `sudo` in Ubuntu.
Even I already followed the post install steps from docker website.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to edit a write protected file. You have two options; edit the file as root, or edit the permissions of the file to allow any user to write to it.

To edit the file as root, open the file in your editor with sudo. For example, "sudo vi /path/to/file" or "sudo nano /path/to/file" depending on your editor of choice.

To change the permissions of the file, use "sudo chmod a+x /path/to/file". Now any user can edit it without the sudo password.